# Groovy MissingPropertyException on HashSet?

Tags: groovy, runtimeexception

My app has the following directory structure:

```
myapp/
    src/
        com.me.myapp/
            Driver.groovy
            Fizz.groovy
            stages (package)
                AbstractStage.groovy
                impl (package)
                    DefaultStage.groovy
```

Where:

```
class Driver {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractStage stage1 = new DefaultStage()
        stage1.derp
    }
}

abstract class AbstractStage {
    Set<Fizz> fizzes = new HashSet<Fizz>()

    void derp() {
        println "I have " + fizzes.size + " attached fizzes!"
    }

    abstract void doSomething()
}

class DefaultStage extends AbstractStage {
    Set<Fizz> executedFizzes = new HashSet<Fizz>()

    @Override
    void doSomething() {
        // TODO: Implement
    }
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: derp for class:com.me.myapp.stages.impl.DefaultStage
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at com.me.myapp.Driver.main(Driver.groovy:6)
```

...where `Driver.groovy:6` corresponds to the line that calls `derp`.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`derp` is a method, not a property, so you need to invoke it:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractStage stage1 = new DefaultStage()
    stage1.derp() // You need the '()' here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Igor Shults (+1) - but very strange. Why would Groovy allow me to do `println "Blah!"` (instead of `println("Blah")`) but I can't drop the parens for `derp` invocations?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja I think it's because it takes a parameter.  So you probably can't do `println` by itself, but `println 'Blah'` is fine because Groovy realizes it's a method and not a property/variable.